Using signals with dynamic angular forms?
I have this shared component which builds a form based on the SearchFilterOption structure.
Here it is (simplified):
import {
    Component,
    EventEmitter,
    inject,
    Input,
    OnChanges,
    Output,
    SimpleChanges,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export type SearchFilterOption = {
    kind: 'text' | 'search' | 'checkbox';
    label: string;
    key: string;
};

@Component({
    selector: 'shared-search-filter',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    templateUrl: './search-filter.component.html',
})
export class SearchFilterComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() filter: { [key: string]: any } = {};
    @Input() filterOptions: readonly SearchFilterOption[] = [];
    @Output() filterChange = new EventEmitter<{ [key: string]: any }>();

    form = new FormGroup({});
    formChange?: Subscription;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes['filterOptions']) {
            const group: { [key: string]: FormControl } = {};
            for (const filter of this.filterOptions) {
                group[filter.key] = new FormControl();
            }
            this.form = new FormGroup(group);
            this.formChange?.unsubscribe();
            this.formChange = this.form.valueChanges
                .pipe(
                    debounceTime(500),
                    distinctUntilChanged(
                        (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
                    )
                )
                .subscribe({
                    next: (values) => {
                        this.filterChange.emit(values);
                    },
                });
        }
        if (changes['filter']) {
            for (const key of Object.keys(this.filter)) {
                const ctrl = this.form.get(key);
                if (ctrl) {
                    ctrl.setValue(this.filter[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

<fieldset [formGroup]="form">
    @for (option of filterOptions; track option; let i = $index) {
        <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
        <input [type]="option.kind" [formControlName]="option.key" />
    }
</fieldset>

and I wanted to try using signals for the input and output of this component, but it all seems to fall apart with errors of missing form fields when I do:
    filter = model<{ [key: string]: any }>({});
    filterOptions = input.required<readonly SearchFilterOption[]>();

    form = new FormGroup({});
    formChange?: Subscription;

    constructor() {
        effect(
            () => {
                const group: { [key: string]: FormControl } = {};
                for (const filter of this.filterOptions()) {
                    group[filter.key] = new FormControl(
                        this.filter()[filter.key]
                    );
                }
                this.form = new FormGroup(group);

                this.formChange?.unsubscribe();
                this.formChange = this.form.valueChanges
                    .pipe(
                        debounceTime(500),
                        distinctUntilChanged(
                            (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
                        )
                    )
                    .subscribe({
                        next: (values) => {
                            this.filter.set(values);
                        },
                    });
            },
            { allowSignalWrites: true }
        );
    }

<fieldset [formGroup]="form">
    @for (option of filterOptions(); track option; let i = $index) {
        <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
        <input [type]="option.kind" [formControlName]="option.key" />
    }
</fieldset>

I've also tried a variation where the subscription uses toSignal, and one that uses computed to build the form and can't really figure out what else to do.
Is there a working method of doing this with signals right now?

Without knowing the nature of the errors, all I can do is guess at the solution and recommend some changes to make the component simpler.

I believe the primary issue in the signals version is likely from looping through filterOptions while building the form with effect.  The timing when effects run won't necessarily be at the point an input changes.  So you need to check to see if the form control exists first or use FormArray and loop through that in the template.
In your view you were looping through filterOptions directly without calling the signal as a function.  If this isn't changed in the signal version then it'll break.  I actually just cautioned about this in an article - Angular Component Bindings: Transitioning from Decorators to Functions.
Don't recreate the form with every change of filterOptions, just reset it and recreate the controls.
In the form resetting effect access filter with untracked.  Otherwise every time it changes then the form has to be remade.
Use a separate effect to update the form values.  Yes this might result in a little redundancy, but it will work in a similar fashion to what you had previously.
Instead of using model, split the filter input and output up so you can use the outputFromObservable to emit changes.  This way you don't have to maintain any subscriptions.

readonly filter = input<{ [key: string]: any }>({});
readonly filterOptions = input.required<readonly SearchFilterOption[]>();
readonly form = new FormGroup({});
readonly filterChange = outputFromObservable(this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))
  ));
constructor() {
  effect(() => {
    this.form.reset();
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => this.form.removeControl(key));
    const filter = untracked(this.filter); // changes here won't cause an effect.
    for (const opt of this.filterOptions()) {
      this.form.addControl(opt.key, new FormControl(filter[opt.key]));
    }
  });
  effect(() => {
    const filter = this.filter();
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.filter)) {
      this.form.get(key)?.setValue(value);
    }
  });
}

<fieldset [formGroup]="form">
  <!-- Don't forget to call fitlerOptions since it is a function now. -->
  @for (option of filterOptions(); track option; let i = $index) {
    @if (form.get(option.key); as formCtrl) {
      <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
      <input [type]="option.kind" [formControl]="formCtrl" />
    }
  }
</fieldset>


These are some nice concepts, but it is this first effect which still causes errors in the form bindings: ERROR Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'test'.
(Note your answer does not do .addControl but I changed it to that)

@Manstie - Besides the missing addControl I found the issue: The input filterOptions was changing before the effect runs.  I updated the answer to use FormGroup but FormArray would probably be better since you can loop through the elements easily in the template.  Maybe you need FormGroup for something else so I won't bother changing it.  Next time put more information in the post so we know exactly what and where the error is.  :-)

Thanks, you can probably remove #2 from your answer since I omitted the whole view code block for brevity instead of pasting it again with () added, but I can see how that can cause pains in answering.

Note: for now this is the best approach I can think of, but when reactive form signals arrives, this code will be redundant.

Your code works fine, all you need to do is to move the for loop that creates the form controls to the ngOnInit.
import {
  Component,
  effect,
  EventEmitter,
  inject,
  input,
  Input,
  model,
  OnChanges,
  Output,
  SimpleChanges,
  untracked,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, Subscription, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { toSignal, outputFromObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

export type SearchFilterOption = {
  kind: 'text' | 'search' | 'checkbox';
  label: string;
  key: string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'shared-search-filter',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `<fieldset [formGroup]="form">
  @for (option of filterOptions; track option; let i = $index) {
      <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
      <input [type]="option.kind" [formControlName]="option.key" />
  }
</fieldset>`,
})
export class SearchFilterComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() filter: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  @Input() filterOptions: readonly SearchFilterOption[] = [];
  @Output() filterChange = new EventEmitter<{ [key: string]: any }>();

  form = new FormGroup({});
  formChange?: Subscription;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['filterOptions']) {
      const group: { [key: string]: FormControl } = {};
      for (const filter of this.filterOptions) {
        group[filter.key] = new FormControl();
      }
      this.form = new FormGroup(group);
      this.formChange?.unsubscribe();
      this.formChange = this.form.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          debounceTime(500),
          distinctUntilChanged(
            (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
          )
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (values) => {
            this.filterChange.emit(values);
          },
        });
    }
    if (changes['filter']) {
      for (const key of Object.keys(this.filter)) {
        const ctrl = this.form.get(key);
        if (ctrl) {
          ctrl.setValue(this.filter[key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'shared-search-filter2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `<fieldset [formGroup]="form">
  @for (option of filterOptions(); track option; let i = $index) {
      <label>{{ option.label }}</label>
      <input [type]="option.kind" [formControlName]="option.key" />
  }
</fieldset>`,
})
export class SearchFilterComponent2 {
  filter = model<{ [key: string]: any }>({});
  filterOptions = input.required<readonly SearchFilterOption[]>();

  form = new FormGroup({});
  formChange?: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.formChange) {
        this.formChange.unsubscribe();
      }
      this.formChange = this.form.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          debounceTime(500),
          distinctUntilChanged(
            (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
          ),
          tap(() => {
            untracked(() => {
              this.filter.set(this.form.value);
            });
          })
        )
        .subscribe();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const group: { [key: string]: FormControl } = {};
    for (const filter of this.filterOptions()) {
      group[filter.key] = new FormControl(this.filter()[filter.key]);
    }
    this.form = new FormGroup(group);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

allowSignalWrites will be removed, use untracked instead

Unfortunately this seems to be the answer - you can not reactively change form controls using signals right now so you can only initialize the values (As of Angular 18.0)
